# Reliable way to detect if running in module vs classic web-worker?

Tags: es6-modules, web-worker

I'm working on some code that needs to change its behavior (using import() vs importScripts()) when running in a [module worker](https://web.dev/module-workers/). Is there any kind of way to detect what "type" of WebWorker you're running in?

The only way I can think of is using this in chrome, but obviously this isn't a great solution...

```
let isModuleWorker = false;
try {
 importScripts('about:blank')
} catch(e) {
  // the full error text in *chrome* is "Module scripts don't support importScripts()"
  isModuleWorker = e.message.contains('Module scripts');
}
```

This is clearly not a good solution, but I haven't seen anything else I can use to make this distinction. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. By the time you run this check your module code would probably have triggered a SyntaxError anyway. Why can't you feature detect at the Worker construction? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62954570/javascript-feature-detect-module-support-for-web-workers

Comment: Because this is running inside of a library that gets used on both classic and module workers and needs to avoid calling importScripts in the module worker.

Comment: Then provide two builds of your library, one a .esm one and a .classic one. Trying to mix these won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Jason Miller on twitter](https://twitter.com/_developit/status/1636476923936112642?s=46&t=9wQBvyF9jObxwp-PzhxOBA) for the answer here:

```
function isModule() {
  try{ 
   importScripts("data:,"); 
   return false; 
  } catch(e) {}
  return true;
}
```

Should work. As opposed to about:blank, this one *won't* throw in a classic worker. :)

Comment: You actually want it to be `"data:text/javascript,"` see https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/8869